# Dark kde plasma 5 session on Gentoo

Tags: kde, gentoo, plasma, kde5

hI upgraded to KDE plasma 5.5.5 following the KDE 4.11 [Gentoo wiki page](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/KDE/Plasma_5_upgrade#SDDM_display_issues):

sddm works fine, I can start a working openbox session with it. (Yes sddm is in the video group)

However, when I start plasma, I get a dark screen with working a mouse and a limited krunner.

I have an  extensive xorg logfile:
http://pastebin.com/m0mHVXJq

I extracted some relevant lines from it:

```
QCoreApplication::arguments: Please instantiate the QApplication object first
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
kscreen: Failed to request backend: unknown error
```

I use openrc and a Nvidia GeForce GTX 760 with 361.28 driver version with 3 displays but two xscreens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to some similar existing bugs on KDE forums, Xinerama can break kde-plasma5, so if you have Xinerama enabled in Xorg's config file (in */etc/X11/xorg.conf* ) , try to disable it. It will be in the *Section "ServerLayout"* :

*Option         "Xinerama" "1"*

So if you have the line like above, change the value to zero:

*Option         "Xinerama" "0"*